# WP Query with meta queries

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, order, sort

I have the following WP_Query:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'       => 'some_cpt',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_key'        => 'active',
  'meta_value'      => 1,
  'orderby'         => 'ranking',
  'order'           => 'ASC'
));
```

Both `active` and `raking` are ACF fields, `True/False` and `Numeric` respectively. I am trying to get all `some_cpt` posts that have `active` set to true and at the same time order them by `ranking`. However, the code above totally ignores `orderby`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `"orderby" => "meta_value_num"` and set a `"meta_query"` at the same time. Then choose the `"meta_key"` you want to order by.

Try:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'some_cpt',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'active',
                'value'   => '1',
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        ),
        'meta_key'       => 'ranking',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am always confused with these meta queries :)